# Repeatable logic for variety of objects

Tags: c#, .net, linq, oracle, refactoring

So here is the code:

```
return new DistrictInfo { 
    rid = Convert.ToUInt32(((OracleNumber)o.GetOracleValue("rid")).Value), 
    doc = Convert.ToUInt16(((OracleNumber)o.GetOracleValue("doctor")).Value), 
    secdoc = Convert.ToUInt16(((OracleNumber)o.GetOracleValue("secdoctor")).Value), 
    num = Convert.ToUInt16(((OracleNumber)o.GetOracleValue("num")).Value), 
    docname = o.GetOracleValue("doctorname") as string, 
    slpuname = o.GetOracleValue("lpuname") as string, 
    reason = o.GetOracleValue("reason") as string, 
    secdocname = o.GetOracleValue("secdocname") as string 
};
```

Now I need to rewrite this code to do a checking whether object property is existing or not. This should be like this piece of code:

```
DistrictInfo di;
if (!(o["rid"].Equals(DBNull.Value)) && !(o.GetOracleValue("rid").Equals(DBNull.Value)) && (((OracleNumber)o.GetOracleValue("rid")).Value != null))
{
    di.rid = Convert.ToUInt32(((OracleNumber)o.GetOracleValue("rid")).Value);
}
```

But I found this code some kind of awkward and not elegant. I did a many of checking 'cause I want to escape exceptions. 
So the question is how can we refactor this code? Tell me your thoughts. I think there's no need in such many checkings. Another thing we need to specify a variety of object property names to do one block of code for all variety members. I think there's ability to use LINQ for that. Also in first piece of code we see different casting so we need to mention it in our new code. 
Thanks in advance guys!

P.S. Library for working with database is dotConnect for Oracle from devArt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to use [UInt32.TryParse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/thh25zy8.aspx) which provides a safe method of converting raw string value to `UInt32`, there are two cases - value can be converted to UInt32 or can not. So basically check return value of `TryParse()` method to see whether value was converted successfully.

So

```
string rawValue = o["rid"].ToString();
UInt32 parsedValue;
if (UInt32.TryParse(rawValue, out parsedValue))
{
    // was converted successfully
}
else
{
    // was not converted
}
```

Regarding automation of this process to handle multiple properties by their names you also need to consider property type, so I can not see *a nice* way to leverage LINQ for this purpose.

**EDIT:** Added proposal regarding automation of a field transformation

You can leverage [Extension Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) feature of `.NET` to decorate `OracleObject` type by a set of helpful methods.

```
public static class OracleObjectExtensions
{
    public static UInt32 GetUInt32Value(this OracleObject oracleObject, string fieldName)
    {
        UInt32 returnValue = default(UInt32);

        if (oracleObject[fieldName] != null)
        {
            string rawValue = oracleObject[fieldName].ToString();
            UInt32.TryParse(rawValue, out returnValue);                
        }

        return returnValue;
    }

    public static UInt16 GetUInt16Value(this OracleObject oracleObject, string fieldName)
    {
        UInt16 returnValue = default(UInt16);

        if (oracleObject[fieldName] != null)
        {
            string rawValue = oracleObject[fieldName].ToString();
            UInt16.TryParse(rawValue, out returnValue);
        }

        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

**EDIT2:** [Extension Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) description

> Extension methods enable you to "add" methods to existing types
>   without creating a new derived type, recompiling, or otherwise
>   modifying the original type. Extension methods are a special kind of
>   static method, but they are called as if they were instance methods on
>   the extended type.

Comment: Propose your way for managing with variety of object properties. It's not only limited to LINQ. Thanks!

Comment: @kseen: 1) what type of the o variable 2) can you use .NET 4.0?

Comment: [here's explanation](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/docs/Devart.Data.Oracle~Devart.Data.Oracle.OracleObject.html). No, there's only .NET Framework 3.5. But if is some good features we can switch to .NET Framework 4. Thanks!

Comment: @kseen : See EDIT part of the my answer. As a case I would suggest to introduce a set of extension methods for the OracleObject class which encapsulates a logic of field transformation. You can improve the extension methods class by adding few private methods to simplify null value checking and to doo not copy the same blocks across the all extension methods

Comment: But I use this class in many part of existing project, so I can't rewrite `OracleObject` to `OracleObjectExtensions` quickly. But idea is very nice. Thanks!

Comment: @kseen : looks like you need to read about extension methods, this feature allows `adding` method to a classes without modifying them, just put class OracleObjectExtensions in your project and you can call methods like `o.GetUInt16Value()` and `o.GetUInt32Value()` where `o` is OracleObject

Comment: @kseen : see EDIT2 with link to the MSDN article as well

Comment: @kseen : no you can use it in 3.5

Comment: So far so good. Any thoughts about one action block per variety of properties?

Comment: @kseen : I can't imagine nice implementation of a such block at least without associations of property name and underlying type, for instance IDictionary<string, TypeCode> for primitive types. Moreover I would not suggest to mix such code into the single code block just to have a single block, keep code base clean

Comment: @kseen : you can do it in a single code block but anyway you'll get something like a bunch of if/else or switch() block, using .NET 4 you can use dynamic feature but anyway it needs to has one method per underlying type and just simplifies type resolving by doing it under the hood, so I would suggest to stick with extension methods, at least you'll have more clear and easily maintainable code base